# NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy returning the wrong type?

Tags: ios, objective-c, azure

I'm working with the Windows Azure SDK for iOS to upload a binary file to Azure Blob Storage. Everything works fine in Debug and when the build is copied straight to the phone, but when it runs on an AdHoc build sent out via TestFlight, I get this exception:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException: -[__NSCFConstantString dataWithBase64DecodedString]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Now the Azure SDK defines dataWithBase64DecodedString in a category on NSData, and the exception occurs in this block of code:

```
void* buffer=malloc(CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH);
CCHmac(kCCHmacAlgSHA256, [cKey bytes], [cKey length], [contentData bytes], [contentData length], buffer);
NSData *encodedData = [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH freeWhenDone:NO]; 
contentMD5 = [encodedData stringWithBase64EncodedData]; /* exception is on this line */
free(buffer);
```

As you can see, encodedData should be an NSData. And sometimes it is. But once compiled and on a phone, far away from my debugger, not so much. Airbrake matches the crash log pulled from the phone.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would guess that the build configuration used when it fails for some reason does not link properly with the azure SDK framework

Comment: you turned out to be correct... adding the -ObjC -load_all flags to the linker fixed it. they were in Debug but not Release.if you add this as an answer I'll accept!

Comment: Nice, i've added an answer and some more details (comment if im incorrect in some way). Also I assume you mean `-all_load` not `-load_all`?

Comment: I realize you've got this figured out now thanks to @MattiasWadman, but for posterity, can you specify what type `encodedData` was? Edit: Oh, nevermind. I see you specified the exception type and it indicates it was an NSData after all, just lacking the message handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because the Azure framework is not properly linked for the build configuration your using when building for device instead of simulator. And as this is a problem with a category method the problem might a [known bug](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1490.html) when linking on x86_64 or ARM. If that is the case try to add `-ObjC -all_load` to the **Other Linker Flags** setting.